# Can't use NLTK on text pulled from the Silmarillion

Tags: python, character-encoding, nltk, textblob

I'm trying to use Tolkein's Silmarillion as a practice text for learning some NLP with nltk.

I am having trouble getting started because I'm running into text encoding issues.

I'm using the TextBlob wrapper (https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob) around NLTK because it's a lot easier.  TextBlog is available at:

The sentence that I can't parse is:

```
"But Húrin did not answer, and they sat beside the stone, and did not speak again".
```

I believe it's the special character in Hurin causing the issue.

My code:

```
from text.blob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob( 'But Húrin did not answer, and they sat beside the stone, and did not speak again' )
b.noun_phrases

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As this is just a for-fun project, I just want to be able to use this text and extracting some attributes and do some basic processing.

How can I convert this text to ASCII when I don't know what the initial encoding is?  I tried to decode from UTF8, then re-encode into ASCII:

```
>>> asc = unicode_text.decode('utf-8')
>>> asc = unicode_text.encode('ascii')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But even that doesn't worry.  Any suggestions are appreciated -- I'm fine with losing the special characters, as long as it's done consistently across the document.

I'm using python 2.6.8 with the required modules also correctly installed.

Comment: Did you try using Unicode strings? Stick a `u` in front of the string and see what happens.

Comment: If you don't know what the initial encoding is: Figure it out. Also I think you are confused when it comes to what Unicode is: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/

Try just the `decode.('utf8')` encoding it with ascii later makes no sense.

Comment: Also: If this still doesn't work, try showing is the exact code you are using, with traceback.

Comment: Note that the Silmarillion is not in the public domain; that site is almost definitely a pirate site.

Comment: @DanielRoseman as long as I'm not republishing anything that is beyond fair use, I should be alright to analyze the text, right?

Comment: @LennartRegebro Thanks for the link, that's a very helpful resource for building a mental model of encodings.  Followup question: when you say to figure out the original encoding, how can I do that?  By looking at the HTML doctype or something?  Is there a standard way to figure out encodings just by looking at the string itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, update TextBlob to the latest version (0.6.0 as of this writing), as there have some unicode fixes in recent updates. This can be done with

```
$ pip install -U textblob
```

Then, use a unicode literal, like so:

```
from text.blob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob( u'But Húrin did not answer, and they sat beside the stone, and did not speak again' )
noun_phrases = b.noun_phrases
print noun_phrases
# WordList([u'h\xfarin'])
print noun_phrases[0]
# húrin
```

This is verified on Python 2.7.5 with TextBlob 0.6.0, but it should work with Python 2.6.8 as well.